# PIMPL not compile on macOS

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

I am reading the [pimpl code from github](https://github.com/sftrabbit/CppPatterns-Patterns/blob/d2719aebee47bb0df990776c890be55636a45bc7/common-tasks/classes/pimpl.cpp), and tried to compile in my macOS laptop as follows:

### file: foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <memory>

class foo::impl
{
  public:
    void do_internal_work()
    {
      internal_data = 5;
    }
  private:
    int internal_data = 0;
};
foo::foo()
  : pimpl{std::make_unique<impl>()}
{
  pimpl->do_internal_work();
}
foo::~foo() = default;
foo::foo(foo&&) = default;
foo& foo::operator=(foo&&) = default;
```

### file: foo.h

```
#include <memory>
class foo
{
  public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
    foo(foo&&);
    foo& operator=(foo&&);
  private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
```

### file man.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    foo x;
}
```

I tried to compile by using `clang++ -std=c++14 main.cc -o main`, but there's an error:

> Undefined symbols
>   for architecture x86_64:   "foo::foo()", referenced from:
>         _main in main-b39a70.o   "foo::~foo()", referenced from:
>         _main in main-b39a70.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're haven't added any of the code from `foo.cpp` to your compiler. Compiling with `clang++ -std=c+14 main.cpp foo.cpp -o main` should fix your problem.